# Computing $\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^{k}(n+1-i)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I dont know how to proceed with solving $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^{k}(n+1-i).$$ Please give advise.

Comment: @RossMillikan In the summand, the power is a constant...

Comment: @DavidMitra:  You are correct.  It is not a duplicate.

Comment: First, find two generating functions for $n^k$ and $1+n$. Then product of them. Next, get the coefficient of $x^n$. You need the eulerian number for the generating function of the sequence $n^k$.

Answer (score 2):

You can factor out the $(n+1)$ to give $(n+1)\sum_{i=1}^n i^k-\sum_{i=1}^n i^{k+1}$  For positive integral $k$ you can use [Faulhaber's formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula).  What kind of $k$ are you considering?

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^{k}(n+1-i)$$

is same as

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}i(n+1-i)^{k}$$

which looks like some combination of Eulerian number.

Answer (score 0):

$H_n^{(k)}=\sum_{i=1}^n i^{-k}$ is by definition the $n$-th harmonic number of order $k$. Thus,
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n i^{k} (n+1-i) = (n+1) H_n^{(-k)}- H_n^{(-k-1)}.
$$
I don't think it can be simplified further, at least considerably and for any $n$ and $k$. Is this what you meant by "solving"?

Comment: Ross: observe that $k$ is not the summation index.

Answer (score 0):

This is a prefix sum of natural numbers. The solution to this is

$$\binom{n+k+1}{k+2}$$