# Calculating the 12 days of christmas by hand

Tags: summation

For an exercise in my math class we are calculating the cost of the 12 days of christmas.

Let's define a set $c$ to be the price of each item in the popular "12 days of christmas" song, from a partridge in a pear tree all the way up to the drummers drumming.

From there I have figured out the formula for the total cost is this:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{12}c_n(n (13-n))$$

And this works. But, it isn't exactly something that you can calculate easily on paper. Is there a way to calculate this cost without having to manually calculate each one and then add it up, perhaps even a way to do it in your head?

EDIT: For those not familiar with the song, [here](http://www.metrolyrics.com/12-days-of-christmas-lyrics-christmas-song.html) is the lyrics, and the list of items is as follows:

```
1 Partridge in a pear tree
2 Turtle Doves
3 French Hens
4 Calling Birds
5 Gold Rings
6 Geese a-Laying
7 Swans a-Swimming
8 Maids a-Milking
9 Ladies Dancing
10 Lords a-Leaping
11 Pipers Piping
12 Drummers Drumming
```

Comment: Can you please list the items in that song for those of us who are not acquainted with it?

Comment: There's an old Peanuts comic strip in which Linus enumerates how many items *of each kind* there are (i.e., 12 partridges in a pear tree, 22 turtle doves, 30 French hens, etc.), but I don't think he adds up the total item count.  I wonder if someone can find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arthur is right - the relationship between $c_n$ is required in order to simplify further.

If, instead, $c_n=1$ (all objects cost $1), the total price is

$$\sum_{n=1}^{12}n(13-n)=\sum_{n=1}^{12}\sum_{m=n}^{12}n=\sum_{m=1}^{12}\sum_{n=1}^m \binom n1=\sum_{m=1}^{12}\binom {m+1}2=\binom{14}3=364\quad\blacksquare$$

This also means that the total number of objects is $364$.

> Curiously and coincidentally, this also means that there is one gift for each day of the year*, apart from one day - perhaps Christmas Eve!
>
> *assuming a non-leap year

Comment: I will add that it is possible to find some posts about this sum for $c_n=1$. In fact, the answer given [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1113556/how-to-show-that-sum-k-1n-kn1-k-binomn23/1113569#1113569) mentioned exactly this song. Some other related posts can be found among questions which are [linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/1113556).

Answer (score 3):

I think that, unless we are told anything about the relationship between the costs of a drumming drummer, a piping piper, a leaping lord, a dancing lady, a milking maid, a swimming swan, a laying goose, a golden ring, a calling bird, a french hen, a turtle dove and a partridge, then there's not much simplification to be done.

Answer (score -1):

When all $c_n=1,$ we are looking at diagonals in Pascal's triangle, as in the answer by hypergeometric

[image]

Comment: And I don't think it's a coincidence that this *looks* like a Christmas tree!

Comment: In fact the gifts can be arranged in tetrahedron with the $n$th layer containing gifts from the $n$th day, resulting in a nice tetrahedral Christmas tree! The total number of elements is a [tetrahedral number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedral_number).

Comment: @hypergeometric, yes. In American pool, related to billiards, the "rack" is a plastic triangle into which fit 15 balls in an equilateral triangle. One may pile more layers and get a tetrahedron of 35 balls.

Comment: You threw up Pascal's triangle without explaining how to use it here.